# How to get a particular word/string in lua regex

Tags: json, regex, string, lua, luci

I have a problem to get a string.
Here is my code:

```
conf = "option fn_o 'Operator'"
print(conf)
local s, e, pa = string.find(conf, "\b(?!option|fn_o)\b\w+")
print(s, e, pa)
```

I want to get an Operator only. In Javascript, that regex works good, but in Lua it doesn't. I think there is no problem because Lua is based on json so it is similar to javascript. Is there any problem?

Comment: Well, Lua has no regex support, it only has Lua patterns. Also, see http://lua-users.org/wiki/JsonModules

Comment: Lua is *not* based on json.

Comment: I'll be frank, I'm a touch offended at that "Lua is based on JSON" comment. Javascript was partially inspired by Lua.

Answer (score 0):

Lua does not support full regular expressions out of the box, but there are libraries that do.

Lua includes *patterns*, which suffice for your task.

This code gets the string inside single quotes:

```
print(string.match(conf, "'(.-)'"))
```

The pattern reads: find a single quote and capture everything until the next single quote.